# How do I do a redirect for a URL with a question mark and equals sign?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the URL of:

https://test.co.uk/blog/?p=308

And I want to redirect it to:

https://test.co.uk/category/article

How do I do this in an .htaccess file? I tried a regular 301 redirect in the .htaccess file, but it doesn't work because of the ? and = symbols.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer here... https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator

It was...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p\=308$
RewriteRule ^blog/$ https://test.co.uk/category/article/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I really would like to motivate you to learn a bit about those different pars of a URL. And what possibilities the apache rewriting module offers to work with that. I can only recommend the official documentation. As typical for OpenSource software that documentation is of high quality: it is precise and comes with great examples. Start here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html